# image on header position comes up with border in chrome and works well in firefox

Tags: html, css

I tried to use logo in the left side on the header position as a linkable object to be linked to home page but could not.

After that i used top-left corner in the header position to link to header page 
and used id as source of image as following:

```
< a href="/"> < img  id="home-link" /> < /a>
```

and the CSS for "home-link" id is :

```
#home-link {
    position: relative;
    width: 360px;    /* width of the logo */
    height: 110px;   /* height of the logo */
    top: 0 left: 0; /* top-left corner of logo */
    border: 0px ;
    float: left;
 }
```

It works fine in Firefox as expected But in chrome it shows border around linkable area and in IE it shows boder as well as image thumbnail,

I do not want border or image thumbnail to be shown as it looks awkward and the users gets to know what i have done

Comment: please provide jsfiddle or codepen code for us

Answer (score 0):

Use this code 
    a:active, a:focus{
    outline: none;
    }
    a:link img, a:visited img, a:hover img { border-style: none; } /* no border on img links */
    a img { color: white; }        /* trick to hide the border in Netscape 4 */

    @media all {                   /* hide the next rule from Netscape 4 */
      a img { color: inherit; }    /* undo the color change above */
    }